# How do i safely remove a secondary mounted root in the fstab file

Tags: debian, filesystems, automounting

On my computer i have 2 drives, a 128GB SSD and a 1.8TB HDD. I mount the HDD on "/home/___/mountpoints/HDD" but today i found that leads me back to "/"

The "fstab" file contains this

```
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation UUID=e20ffb34-68e3-4d48-ba53-5913d8b11d4a   /                          ext4   errors=remount-ro   0 1 
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation UUID=575c62d0-f74d-4d80-9682-f2a491c4ab38   none                       swap   sw                  0 0  /dev/sdb1                              /home/____/mountpoints/HDD   ext4   users               0 0
```

Is it safe to remove the second line and remount my HDD there or do i need to do it another way? (if it helps i use debian 11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/etc/fstab` **should** look more like this:

```
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation 
UUID=e20ffb34-68e3-4d48-ba53-5913d8b11d4a   /    ext4   errors=remount-ro   0 1 
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation 
UUID=575c62d0-f74d-4d80-9682-f2a491c4ab38  none  swap   sw                  0 0  
/dev/sdb1           /home/____/mountpoints/HDD   ext4   users               0 0
```

The lines beginning with the `#` character are comment lines and have no technical effect: your current comment lines were created by the Debian OS installer to describe the system configuration at the time of installation.

You apparently have added the **fifth** line.

Since on modern systems disks can be hot-plugged, the device names can sometimes vary from one boot to the next. Because of this, the current best practice is to not use device names, but identifiers that are written to the actual disk/partition/filesystem you wish to refer to. Here, the `UUID=` refers to a *filesystem UUID* (or an equivalent *swap partition UUID*).

The comment line says your root filesystem was on `/dev/sda1` during installation, but since you say your `/home/____/mountpoints/HDD` now leads you back to `/`, the detection order must have changed at some point, and now your root filesystem is at `/dev/sdb1`. Because of this, the 5th line of your `/etc/fstab` causes the root filesystem to be mounted a second time to your `/home/____/mountpoints/HDD`.

You should be able to simply unmount the extra mount of the root filesystem, with e.g.

```
umount /home/____/mountpoints/HDD
```

Deleting (or commenting out) the **5th** line of your `/etc/fstab` will also work. However, instead of deleting the line, you might want to use e.g. `lsblk -o +UUID` to find out the filesystem UUID of your HDD, and change the `/dev/sdb1` on that `/etc/fstab` line to the appropriate `UUID=...` string instead.